# How do i see if a "file_name" is contained in @files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my controller i have the following:

```
@documents = Document.find(:all, :order => "section asc, sub_section asc, position asc, name asc")
@files = Dir.glob("public/downloads/*").sort
```

In my view i have the following:

```
<% @documents.each do |d| -%>
    <tr class="<%= cycle("","alt") %>">
        <td><%= d.name %></td>
        <td><%= d.file_name %></td>
        <td><%= d.description %></td>
        <td>
            <%= link_to "Edit", edit_document_path(d) %><br>
            <%= link_to "Del", document_path(d), :confirm => "Are you sure boogerhead?", :class => "destroy", :method => :delete %>
        </td>
    </tr>
<% end -%>
```

If file_name is not contained in @files then the link on another page that is dependent on that name (file_name) will not work. If there is not a match, I'll color code file_name to indicate there is a problem. How do i check to see if file_name is contained in @files?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Array#include?` method checks whether a given item is contained in an array, so you can do:

```
if @files.include?(d.file_name)
  # It is included
else
  # It isn't
end
```

Comment: I needed to modify the first line to "if @files.include?("public/downloads/" + d.file_name)" and then it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can also check if a file exists somewhere in your @directory loop:

```
File.exist?(file_path)
```

or if I'm reading your code right, you're checking if a document has a certain file, right? If that is so, why not use paperclip gem so you can add an association that your document should have a file.

Or if that's not possible, you can still transfer that logic into your Document model like so:

```
 def has_file
   File.exist?("public/downloads/#{file_name}")
 end
```

then in your loop,

```
<% @documents.each do |d| -%>
  <% if d.has_file %>
    <tr class="<%= cycle("","alt") %>">
      <td><%= d.name %></td>
      <td><%= d.file_name %></td>
      <td><%= d.description %></td>
      <td>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_document_path(d) %><br>
        <%= link_to "Del", document_path(d), :confirm => "Are you sure boogerhead?", :class => "destroy", :method => :delete %>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: Great suggestions. Going to check out the paperclip gem.